# Changes to php.ini not reflecting - php5 via fpm on nginx

Tags: php, nginx

I've been trying to change some settings in php.ini - namely the 'upload_max_filesize' setting from 2M to 5M.

**Some info**

I have a page with the following php:

```
<?php echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize'), ", " , ini_get('post_max_size'); ?>
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

This outputs `2M, 8M` and then the phpinfo which has `Loaded Configuration File /etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`

It is also scanning for extra ini files under `/etc/php5/fpm/conf.d` but none of those files contain the 'upload_max_filesize' directive.

NB: I'm not particularly fluent in unix and very unfamiliar with nginx.

**Things I've tried**

```
grep -R 'upload_max_filesize' /etc/*
```

This only shows `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` and `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`. I changed the file under the cli folder for good measure but still nothing.

I have been editing the files with `sudo vim php.ini`

I've tried restarting the nginx server with `sudo /etc/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload` as well as `sudo /etc/nginx/sbin/nginx -s stop` followed by `sudo /etc/nginx/sbin/nginx`.

I have tried renaming the `php.ini` to `php.ini.deleted` and restarted the server - nothing changes at all. `phpinfo()` still shows that the server is using `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini`.

**tl;dr**

I believe `phpinfo()` is reporting incorrect information - any suggestions as to where I might perhaps find the config file that nginx is actually using?

**Edit** Thanks to D.Kasipovic - solution was very simple and was just that php5-fpm was a service that needed to be restarted. I forgot that it ran as a service rather than like a module under Apache...

Comment: Have you also restarted the npm process? Alternatively try the `.user.ini` first.

Comment: Have you tried to restart php5-fpm like `service php5-fpm restart`?

Comment: @mario doesn't `nginx -s stop` kill the process? Where might I find this `.user.ini` file?

Comment: Not necessarily. Create one in your DOCUMENT_ROOT.

Comment: @mario thanks for your suggestions! D. Kasipovic's solution worked for me though

Comment: Dont sweat it, I had same issue when I transfered from Apache to NGINX + FPM. Had a little trouble adjusting to new environment.